# Prolog, passing facts into a rule's argument list

Tags: prolog

presume I have a sequence of facts:

```
fact(a,1).
fact(b,10).
fact(c,100).
```

I want to be able to use a rule of this type:

```
rule(fact(A,10),fact(c,B)):-
  write(A),
  write(B).
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You're saying *I want to be able to use a rule of this type*, but you haven't said what you want the rule to mean or do, or what "type" you are talking about. Based upon your example rule, it looks like you may not understand how Prolog works (it's not clear why you're passing `fact/2` terms as arguments to the predicate).

Comment: People often ask questions when they are do not know how something works.  Hence the rule's applicability or non-applicability.
Prolog offers constructs such as write(), that are simple on the face of it.
There are three facts that are indisputably well formed (or are they?).
What remains is the convergence of the argument list and those rules.  The why of it is immaterial.  If I am misunderstanding the application of facts within a argument list for rule/2, then I would appreciate an explanation for how to pass facts into it.

Comment: Right, but it was not clear at all to me what you were trying to ask. In fact, there was no question stipulated in your post. You simply said, *I want to be able to use rules of this type* which is quite vague.  You don't "pass facts" as arguments in Prolog. @TomasBy gave a direct answer if your intended rule was just to query the two facts with variables `A` and `B` and write out the results. Although normally you would write your predicate as, `rule(A, B) :- fact(A, 10), fact(c, B).` then call it: `rule(A, B)` and Prolog will display the solutions for `A` and `B`. You don't need `write`.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. By.  You took my submission into calm and thoughtful deliberation and delivered a well tempered (and useful) response.

Comment: It is quite difficult to know if the response was useful because it is still unclear what you are after. The chances are, you are even more confused than before, because you think you understand but you don't. But this is just my opinion (I did not vote to close your question).

Answer (score 1):

You use the fact predicate as a query, e.g.

```
rule :-
  fact(A,10),
  fact(c,B),
  write(A),
  write(B).
```

Addition: to interpret your question more literally, you want to do something like

```
rule(P1,P2):-
  call(P1), call(P2),
  write(A),
  write(B).
```

but then you need to somehow specify the relations A-P1 & B-P2, which I don't think can be done in any simple, useful way.

So perhaps what you want is

```
rule(X,Y) :-
  fact(A,X),
  fact(Y,B),
  write(A),
  write(B).
```

Comment: I feel like `?- rule(fact(A,10),fact(c,B)), write(A), write(B). rule(P1,P2):- call(P1), call(P2).` might be a good variant to include in your answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity What's troubling me is the suggestion to use `call/1` in this way may not be good advice at all depending upon what the OP is trying to achieve. I think the last solution given above comes closest to what I *think* they're asking.

Comment: @lurker - Yes, I agree.